# Load JS file only in specific template

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script

`is_page` is working fine as it detects the slug. However, `is_page_template` function isn't and so I tried `global $template` too but that's not working either. How can I resolve this issue?

I want to load the the JS file for the page `template-parts/content.php`

```
function software_enqueue() {
   if ( is_page( 'software' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('sticky-kit.min.js', get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/assets/js/sticky-kit.min.js', false ,'1.0', 'all' );
   }
   global $template;
    if ( basename( $template ) === 'template-parts/content.php' ) {
      wp_enqueue_script('sticky-kit.min.js', get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/assets/js/sticky-kit.min.js', false ,'1.0', 'all' );
   }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'software_enqueue' );
```

btw, I tried calling the file (fullwidth.php) too using the code below but that didn't work:

```
if ( is_page_template('fullwidth.php') ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('sticky-kit.min.js', get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/assets/js/sticky-kit.min.js', false ,'1.0', 'all' );
   }
```

**fullwidth.php**

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Full Width
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area content-fullwidth">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;

            endwhile; // End of the loop.
            ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

Comment: you can enqueue the file in the template file before to call `get_header`.

Comment: `is_page_template('fullwidth.php')` is correct, and should work. The only reason it wouldn't is if `fullwidth.php` was in a sub-folder, in which case it should be something like `templates/fullwidth.php`, or if the template wasn't assigned to the page via _Page Attributes > Template_ when editing the page, in which case you'll need to explain how you're actually using this template.

Comment: fullwidth.php is in the base folder and i'm confused too as to why it's not working! The page was assigned using "Full Width" option which is the template name from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Resolved by putting it directly on the page as Cenay mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaperto is correct, you can enqueue in the actual page template file you want the javascript to appear in. If it would only need to be in a single template file (rather than every page that is fullwidth), I would create a new one which includes the JS, and use that as the template for the page. Ie:

```
<?php
/** 
* Template Name: Sticky Kit Enabled 
*/ 

wp_enqueue_script('sticky-kit.min.js', get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/assets/js/sticky-kit.min.js', false ,'1.0', 'all' );

get_header(); ?>

<section id="primary" class="content-area content-fullwidth">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;

        endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</section><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: I'll give this method a go. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. It's resolved. I'm wondering why my original code isn't though!